# Phaser doesn't load audio function in json file

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Phaser loads all the files except it is failing to load audio file.

**JSON** file with assets to load (image and audio file):

```
 "assets": {
    "background_image": {
      "type": "image",
      "source": "assets/images/background.png"
    },
    "background_audio":{
      "type": "audio",
      "source":"assets/sound/intro_screen_sound.wav"
    }
```

**Code** used to load JSON file:

```
 RPG.LoadingState.prototype.preload = function () {
     "use strict";
     var assets, asset_key, asset;
     assets = this.level_data.assets;
     for (asset_key in assets) { // load assets according to asset key
         asset = assets[asset_key];
         switch (asset.type) {
             case "image":
                 this.game.load.image(asset_key, asset.source);
                 break;
             case "audio":
                 this.game.load.audio(asset_key, asset.source);
                 break;
             case "spritesheet":
                 this.load.spritesheet(asset_key, asset.source, asset.frame_width, asset.frame_height, asset.frames, asset.margin,
asset.spacing);
                 break;
             case "tilemap":
                 this.load.tilemap(asset_key,asset.source,null,Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
                 break;
         }
         this.load.text("user_input", this.level_data.user_input);
     }
```

Comment: What does the browser's console tell you, if anything?

Comment: I can't find any of audio source